# How to pin current location of user using Google API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have added the GoogleMaps API and it is showing the hard coded location, with the following code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class OurViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    // Other variables

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        //google map 
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(13.034211,
        longitude: 77.5670453, zoom: 16)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.034211, 77.5670453)
        marker.title = "globals inc"
        marker.snippet = "bangalore"
        marker.map = mapView
    }
}
```

Can some body help my pointing out how to get the user location?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through - [This](https://github.com/ziyang0621/GoogleMapsCurrentLocationRotation-Swift/blob/master/GoogleMapSwift/ViewController.swift)

And
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: its giving error exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_1386_invop,subcode=0x0)